# Get instance of AppBar Button

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my xaml I have 2 different `AppBarr`s in resources:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar1" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain1" IconUri="/icons/appbar.radeos.png" Text="radeos"
                                        Click="abMain_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>

    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar2" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain" IconUri="/icons/appbar.radeos.png" Text="radeos"
                                        Click="abMain_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abLast" IconUri="/icons/appbar.back.rest.png" Text="last"
                                        Click="abLast_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abNext" IconUri="/icons/appbar.next.rest.png" Text="next"
                                        Click="abNext_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abClosePopup" IconUri="/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="close"
                                        Click="abClosePopup_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And I switch it in code, when I need it using:

```
ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar1"];
```

or

```
ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar2"];
```

Question is: How get instance of AppBarr Buttons (ex. `abMain1`) in any place in code? 
 Visual Studio see this field, but it always `null` (because it in resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access like so

```
ApplicationBarIconButton abMain1Button = (ApplicationBarIconButton) ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just solved my problem. I your answer ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] - it's a object witch need to cast to ApplicationBarIconButton. I use this construction:  var abMain1Button = (ApplicationBarIconButton) ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];